# Extensible add_meta_box with apply filters

Tags: metabox

Im trying to give the user the option to extend/add the fields for a given metabox using filters using the class https://github.com/bainternet/My-Meta-Box

this is what i have and it shows the fields OK http://pastebin.com/mvFyyKfa

```
    //array of options
    $clients_info_array=array(
            array(
                    'id'            => 'client_first_name_field',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'options'       => array(
                            'name'  =>      'First Name',
                    )
            ),     
            array(
                    'id'            => 'client_last_name_field',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'options'       => array(
                            'name'  =>      'Last Name',                           
                    )
            ),             
    );

    $clients_info_array = apply_filters('clients_extra_input',$clients_info_array);


    foreach($clients_info_array as $single_client_info){
            if($single_client_info['type']=='text'){
                    $clients_info_metabox->addText($single_client_info['id'],$single_client_info['options']);
            }
    }
```

I`m trying to add a new field using this code

```
add_filter('clients_extra_input','custom_dog_name_field');
function custom_dog_name_field($arr){

    $arr[]= array(
                    'id'            => 'client_dog_name_field_id',
                    'type'          => 'text',
                    'options'       => array(
                            'name'  =>      'Dog Name',
                    )
            );

    return $arr;
}
```

but no matter where i place it ( functions.php or a new plugin with just that code ) , i cant see the extra field on the metabox.

Am I doing something wrong ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind , 
i was hooking the metaboxes on plugin_run()

Moved them to admin_menu() and now it works OK

Regards